# Johny-Five Board not ready

Tags: javascript, johnny-five

i got a problem with the initialition of the board from johnny-five

i got an arduino with the StandardFirmata on it (i also tried StandardFirmataPlus).

```
var board = new five.board()
```

works correct when i try it on a mac, it finds the right port and connects to it without problems. but under windows 10 (i also tried windows 7, no changes) i have to work with:

```
var board = new five.board( { port: "COM11"})
```

the problem is that the com port with the arduino is not allways the same, so i have to change the adress in the code. this is quite a problem because i want to automatize the program.

does anyone have an idea why it works on a mac and not with windows? 
is there a possibility how i can make him correct to the right port without having to change the code?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

johnny-five will [automatically](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Board#parameters) detect the Arduino port, just don't pass the `port` option to `five.board`.